# Creating Tag Longer than Limit doesn't Give Warning

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don’t allow submitting questions/edits if a tags length exceeds the limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50107/dont-allow-submitting-questions-edits-if-a-tags-length-exceeds-the-limit)

Probably doesn't get much more low priority than this, but when you create a tag that is longer than a tag can be, there is no warning and it just creates a cropped tag.

Comment: Easy fix: Do not invent new tags!