# Don't allow submitting questions/edits if a tag's length exceeds the limit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, character-limit

When adding more than 5 tags, we can't post or submit edits. However, when exceeding the length limit of 25 characters for a tag, no such restriction is in place.

This leads to some broken tags like [visual-web-developer-expr](/questions/tagged/visual-web-developer-expr), [visual-studio-20xx-expres](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-20xx-expres), [visual-studio-express-20x](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-express-20x), etc....

Could we have the same restriction from posting/submitting here as for the tag count limit? Or alternatively at least a warning?

Comment: And also with a tag that was suppose to read `always-friday-in-wonderland` instead reads `always-friday-in-wonderla`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, we now disallow submission on new questions and edit to questions, when any tag length exceeds the maximum (25 characters).

Answer (score 2):

I agree, especially since I contributed to the `[visual-web-developer-expr]` broken tag issue   by accident, only realizing it months later when someone edited my tags.